# Cloud Init isn't adding Apt sources BEFORE apt update is executed

Tags: ubuntu, apt, cloud-init

I'm trying to install packages from docker and k8s.io, but `package_update: true` isn't using the newly added sources, and finding those packages fails.

Here is part of the cloud-init config:

```yml
apt:
  sources:
    docker:
      keyid: '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88'
      keyserver: 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg'
      source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic stable'
    kubernetes:
      keyid: 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436'
      keyserver: 'https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key'
      source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /'
  conf: |
    APT {
        Get {
            Assume-Yes 'true';
            Fix-Broken 'true';
        }
    }
package_update: true
package_upgrade: false
packages:
  - apt-transport-https
  - ca-certificates
  - curl
  - gpg
  - gnupg
  - containerd.io
  - kubelet
  - kubeadm
  - kubectl
```

From `cloud-init-output.log`:

```
Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu2 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 10 Dec 2023 19:37:18 +0000. Up 12.34 seconds.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease [256 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 Packages [135 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main Translation-en [40.5 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7232 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1560 B]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [150 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/restricted Translation-en [24.6 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [420 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/universe amd64 Packages [52.1 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/universe Translation-en [18.6 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3860 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [788 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4284 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/multiverse Translation-en [932 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [232 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease [90.8 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [465 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe amd64 Packages [15.2 MB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe Translation-en [5951 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3793 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [303 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/multiverse amd64 Packages [239 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/multiverse Translation-en [113 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.6 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8356 B]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 Packages [170 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main Translation-en [52.3 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7240 B]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1676 B]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [153 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/restricted Translation-en [25.0 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [420 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [72.3 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe Translation-en [26.3 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3864 B]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [820 B]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [4284 B]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/multiverse Translation-en [932 B]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [232 B]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3928 B]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/universe Translation-en [1392 B]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 27.6 MB in 5s (5384 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu2 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 10 Dec 2023 19:37:28 +0000. Up 22.09 seconds.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
E: Unable to locate package kubelet
E: Unable to locate package kubeadm
E: Unable to locate package kubectl
```

`/var/log/cloud-init.log` (relevant entries):

```
2023-12-10 20:29:41,050 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running update-sources using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/instances/i-bf7816b90d424023a2255369dc5b7609/sem/update_sources'>)
2023-12-10 20:29:47,970 - util.py[DEBUG]: apt-update [eatmydata apt-get --option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io --assume-yes --quiet update] took 6.919 seconds
2023-12-10 20:29:48,221 - cc_apt_configure.py[DEBUG]: adding source/key '{'keyid': '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88', 'keyserver': 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg', 'source': 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic stable'}'
2023-12-10 20:29:48,514 - cc_apt_configure.py[DEBUG]: adding source/key '{'keyid': 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436', 'keyserver': 'https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key', 'source': 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /'}'
2023-12-10 20:29:48,907 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: update-sources already ran (freq=once-per-instance)
```

VM's `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` order:

```
cloud_config_modules:
  - apt_pipelining
  - apt_configure
cloud_final_modules:
  - package_update_upgrade_install
```

From VM:

Sources are created

```shell
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
docker.list  kubernetes.list
```

When manually updating, the sources are found:

```shell
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic InRelease [48.8 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease                                                   
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease                          
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic/stable amd64 Packages [2926 B]       
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease                                
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease   
Get:6 https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb  InRelease [1186 B]
Get:8 https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb  Packages [7750 B]
Fetched 60.7 kB in 1s (48.2 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
50 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Installing `containerd.io`:

```shell
$ sudo apt install containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  containerd.io
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 117 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.6.25-1 [28.7 MB]
Fetched 28.7 MB in 1s (25.4 MB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package containerd.io.
(Reading database ... 65188 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../containerd.io_1.6.25-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking containerd.io (1.6.25-1) ...
Setting up containerd.io (1.6.25-1) ...

Configuration file '/etc/containerd/config.toml'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** config.toml (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? N
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/containerd.service → /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-3) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

Comment: I see this is Ubuntu. What cloud/VM are you running under? Are you using a stock image from a cloud or from the Ubuntu website, and has the image been customized at all? If customized, run `cloud-init clean` before using it. I ran this locally on Mantic and don't see the same problems you do. Apt update shouldn't run before the configuration.

This may be more appropriate as a bug on https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/issues .It'd be useful to have the entire tarball (with any sensitive data redacted) from `cloud-init collect-logs --include-userdata`.

Comment: I put up a repo of everything exact (Vagrant `ubuntu/mantic64`).  I'll grab the logs and update the question: https://github.com/johnmanko/vagrant-k8s-cluster